# Difference between Open Beta and Production

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Google Play Console allows you to publish your app in Open Beta and Production. Both are open to unlimited public. So what is the difference between the both and even if someone remains in Open Beta indefinitely, will there be any cons?

Answer (score 1):

Production is available to all users.

Beta users need to choose to join the beta program.

**Differences Open Beta vs Production**

- Beta users can't write reviews - They can only give private feedback.
- Beta users get access to versions of the app that you publish on the beta channel before you publish them in Production. This means you can use them to test new versions to find bugs and fix them before pushing the release to Production. If utilized correctly, this will increase the chance of a high quality app and reduce the impact of errors on your users.

Comment: Will the private feedback translate to review when the app is pushed to production from open beta?

Comment: No. It doesn't translate to a review and doesn't contribute to the app rating.